# Strange resource not found issue?

Tags: android, resources, soundpool

i seem to be having a very strange problem, when the app is run on my test phone it works perfectly, and plays a sound from the raw folder via soundpool on button press, however when i submit my app to testing after building it it crashes on 120+ devices for 'Resource not found'

codes below: Please also note, the file is in fact there, in both the R file, in the compiled APK file and i have also cleaned numerous times.

http://www.appthwack.com/public/FUVGFZn42q

```
'01-03 21:09:36.828 26762 26762 W System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{appinventor.ai_Broak.PaintballWiz/com.muo.paintballwiz.PaintballWiz}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/pballshot.ogg from drawable resource ID #0x7f050000 - 1 occurrence'



soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);

//soundPoolMap = new SparseIntArray();
soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

// soundPoolMap.put(soundID, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.midi_sound, 1));
int myAudioFile = getResId("pballshot", R.raw.class);
soundPoolMap.put(soundID, soundPool.load(PaintballWiz.this, myAudioFile, 1));
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
leftVolume = curVolume / maxVolume;
rightVolume = curVolume / maxVolume;
soundPool.play(soundID, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);
soundPool.play(soundID, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try and put your audio files into the 'assets' folder. Then use an AssetManager to access the file.

Comment: Oddly enough, when i move the code from the oncreate into an on button press the crashes stop? 0.o

Comment: Interesting.. not all Android devices are created equal, could be that by having it in oncreate it's simply being called too early. Post a bit more code if you want, difficult to help more without getting a fuller picture of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it sounds like the resource is not one of your own files. and that you are using a phone's resource. I know you state its in the compiled APK, but I think you should double check that

If this is the case, then the resource you are using is one, not guaranteed to be on an android phone. And so is missing in some devices.

The solution is to copy it and put this in your own resource folder, so that it is packaged into the APK and distributed to any phone that installs your app.

If it is already in your APK, but is also a phone resource, make sure it is pointing correctly to the one you have in your APK and not the phone's location.

Comment: Nope, it's my own audio recording, in OGG format 64k bitrate and placed in the raw folder.